# Where is the lotion?

Tags: torchlight-2

I am in Act 1 in the Slavers Stockade and I came across a giant pit at the end and there was a bucket. I hover my mouse over it and it says "put the lotion in the bucket". It cracks me up for the "Silence of the Lambs" quote. I am eager to know

- Is there really a lotion?
- and where can I find it?

Comment: On its skin, or it gets the hose again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a bottle of lotion; it's an unmarked item that sparkles every so often, kind of like the hidden switches that open secret rooms. If I remember correctly, it appears in the map as a green bottle. You'll find it in one of the cells at the top (northern end) of that particular map. Here's [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UWlzdVSH2U) from YouTube that should give you an idea of where to find it.

**Don't watch all the way to the end if you want the loot drop to be a surprise (you only need to watch the first 7 seconds or so).**